# Azure AD upload service principals key credentials certificate

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a problem with the GraphAPI from Microsoft.

In the documentation I do not get further from point 4 on.
Link: [Automate SAML-based SSO app configuration with Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-saml-sso-configure-api#step-4-configure-signing-certificate)

My problem is:
In the documentation is "Extract the private and public key Base64 encoded from the PFX file".
I have tried many things but everything I have tried I always get a error.
I do not know how to upload a sign certificate.

The upload of a Verify certificate works without problems.

The error code von GraphAPI is:

```
Error: Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: The value for the property "usage" in one of your credentials is invalid. Acceptable values are Sign, Verify.
```

Do any of you have any idea what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, the value for the property `usage` uses **Sign** or **Verify**.
And it is also noted in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-saml-sso-configure-api#request-7).

> The "key" value in the keyCredentials property is shortened for
> readability. The value is base 64 encoded. For the private key the
> property usage is "Sign". For the public key the property usage is
> "Verify".

Check the property `usage` of **keyCredentials**.

```
"keyCredentials":[
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": "lY85bR8r6yWTW6jnciNEONwlVhDyiQjdVLgPDnkI5mA=",
            "endDateTime": "2021-04-22T22:10:13Z",
            "keyId": "4c266507-3e74-4b91-aeba-18a25b450f6e",
            "startDateTime": "2020-04-22T21:50:13Z",
            "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
            "usage": "Sign",
            "key":"MIIKIAIBAz.....HBgUrDgMCERE20nuTptI9MEFCh2Ih2jaaLZBZGeZBRFVNXeZmAAgIH0A==",
            "displayName": "CN=awsAPI"
        }]
```

Comment: "Extract the private and public key Base64 encoded from the PFX file"
How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, I am following exactly the documentation.
My JSON looks like:

```
{
  "keyCredentials": [
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": "ZWxYN1pOc21Od3NJUU4rYjduTUNxclJ5emtrPQ==",
      "endDateTime": "2030-07-08T16:06:27+02:00",
      "keyId": "a3892889-b097-4c36-ac69-5fb3d18d2396",
      "startDateTime": "2020-07-09T16:06:27+02:00",
      "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
      "usage": "Sign",
      "key": "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",
      "displayName": "CN=awsAPI",
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.keyCredential"
    },
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": "ZWxYN1pOc21Od3NJUU4rYjduTUNxclJ5emtrPQ==",
      "endDateTime": "2030-07-08T16:06:27+02:00",
      "keyId": "b022f959-3f36-4880-8537-265f62ba9df0",
      "startDateTime": "2020-07-09T16:06:27+02:00",
      "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
      "usage": "Verify",
      "key": "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",
      "displayName": "CN=awsAPI",
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.keyCredential"
    }
  ],
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.servicePrincipal"
}
```

As you can see, I use the values **Sign** and **Verify** for the property of "usage"

```
Error: Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: The value for the property "usage" in one of your credentials is invalid. Acceptable values are Sign, Verify.
```

To reproduce the error above I left the keys unshortened